# Raycasting на Unity2D (С#)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно чтобы события `OnBeginDrag`, `OnDrag` и `OnEndDrag` работали от прикосновения. А также чтобы стандартные элементы `UI`, такие как кнопки и слайдеры - работали от прикосновения на телефоне тоже. Я делаю проект `WebGL` для запуска на телефонных браузерах. В одном месте нашёл, что для этого нужен `Raycasting`, но как его задавать для всех стандартных функций и вызывать события мыши не нашёл. Ни куда прикреплять скрипт, ни как задать в нём события я пока не понял...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Не нужны никакие касты. Вроде бы `UI` реагирует на управление через прикосновения и так.

А способов есть минимум два:

**1) способ** - использовать **[EventTrigger](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventTrigger.html)**.

Для этого на нужном элементе `UI`, например на `Image` выбираем `AddComponent->Event->EventTrigger`
Появится:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее нажимаем `Add New Event Type` добавляем три эвента `BeginDrag, Drag, EndDrag`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На КАЖДЫЙ из этих эвентов можно добавить метод, описанный в скрипте. Сам скрипт должен висеть на каком либо элементе. В данном случае тот самый скрипт будет висеть все на том же элементе `Image`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам скрипт `Test.cs`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {

    public void OnBeginDrag2() {
        Debug.Log("Begin drag2");     
    }

    public void OnDrag2() {
        Debug.Log("Dragging2...");

        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;        
    }

    public void OnEndDrag2() {
        Debug.Log("End drag2");
    }
}
```

Только вместо `Input.mousePosition` отслеживать прикосновение, например:

```
if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
    transform.position = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
}
```

Или обработка множества каких либо нажатий:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i) {
        var phase = Input.GetTouch(i).phase;
        if (phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {      
            // do smth...
        }
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**2) способ** - использовать интерфейсы **[IBeginDragHandler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IBeginDragHandler.OnBeginDrag.html)**, **[IDragHandler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html)**, **[IEndDragHandler](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IEndDragHandler.html)**

Тут все проще. Берете скрипт, "наследуете" в нем `IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler` и реализуете обязательные методы `OnBeginDrag`, `OnDrag` и `OnEndDrag` ровно тем же способом, что в первом скрипте.. Скрипт вешаете на тот элемент, который будет отвечать за это...

Как пример:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour,  IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Debug.Log("Begin drag");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            Debug.Log("Dragging...");
            transform.position = Input.GetTouch(0).position;            
        }        
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Debug.Log("End drag");
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я использовал второй способ, тольконе сделал тач вместо мыши. Только мне нужно дрэгать итем на специальный слот. Я использовал готовое решение в таком виде, что оно использует код:
            `GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().blocksRaycasts = true;`
Чтобы мышь видела объект, который находится под тем объектом, который она тащит. Я так понимаю, рэйкаст всё-равно нужен, чтобы деланье прозрачным тащимый объект имело смысл.
 И ещё - кнопки и слайдеры на UI работают только на компьютере, а на телефоне - нет. Я тоже читал что вроде как оно должно реагировать на прикосновения, но не реагирует.

Comment: У специального слота нужно реализовать  `OnDrop` теми же способами. Всё. Никаких рейкастов.......`деланье прозрачным тащимый объект имело смысл` -----> а в чем проблема сделать прозрачным данный объект без рейкаста, что-то я не понимаю.............Берете и делаете его прозрачным :-D   `кнопки и слайдеры на UI работают только на компьютере, а на телефоне - нет` --------> все работает. ..возможно вам где-нибудь ошибку показывает в результате чего не работает, а вы игнорите ошибки и ничего не делаете..

Comment: Спасибо. 
Он будет фиксировать событие покоординатно, а объект который мы тащим будет по тем координатам где палец всегда. Следовательно, мы будем вызывать событие конца касания на объекте, который тащим, а не на объекте, на который перетащили. А надо на том (чтобы внести его в переменную объекта и припэрэнтить к нему наш тащимый объект)
На одном приложении кнопки работают, а слайдеры нет. Никаких сообщений с ошибками ни в эдиторе ни на сайте нет. Только в начале предупреждение что webGL может не поддерживаться на мобильном, я кликаю ок, и всё запускается.

Comment: `он будет фиксировать событие покоординатно, а объект который мы тащим будет по тем координатам где палец всегда. Следовательно, мы будем вызывать событие конца касания на объекте, который тащим, а не на объекте, на который перетащили. А надо на том (чтобы внести его в переменную объекта и припэрэнтить к нему наш тащимый объект)` вы заблуждаетесь....сильно заблуждаетесь..хотя бы попробовали бы... `drag` на перетаскиваемом объекте чтоб был, а `drop` на слоте.... все работает как часы: http://s016.radikal.ru/i334/1603/17/47e6d9bbe9bb.gif    ..мышка у меня эмулирует `touch` в эмуляторе андройда

Comment: Спасибо. Только дроп этот вызывается в скрипте который на перетаскиваемом объекте, или в том, который на слоте возникает?
И да, я нашел ошибки. они просто не каждый раз высвечиваются. uncaught abort (110) пишет, и дальше список всех моих .js скриптов.
Кнопка то работает, то не работает от попытки к попытке, а слайдеры вообще не работают. Мне кажется это ошибка юзер интерфейса на телефонных версиях браузера и надо просто сделать искуственный вызов кликов рэй каст таки необходим.

Comment: Ну я же написал, что drop на слоте.... это же логично даже)) ведь на слот кидаем..... соответственно там и код, отлавливающий событие))  ну вот видите, ошибки всё же есть... вот скорее всего из-за них что-то и не работает......

Comment: Я разобрался, спасибо. А как быть с Ui элементами? Ошибка abort(110) неисправимая, так сами разработчики говорят. Наверное, из-за неё не работают некоторые события. Можно ли как то искусственно вызвать их?