# Создание кликабельного GameOBject'a

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется набор gameobject'ов который будут работать как кнопки.
На них висит box коллайдер и также кодом вешается pointclick триггер (вызывает функцию с параметрами, параметры разные для каждой "кнопки").
А дальше встает вопрос. Как привести это всё в рабочее состояние, чтобы триггер срабатывал на клик?

Как заставить сработать ивент?

Comment: мне кажется тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498568/191482  первый способ именно то, что вам нужно

Comment: Дочитал до:
> Только вместо Input.mousePosition отслеживать прикосновение...

Дальше не понял((((. 
1) Как отловить нажатие для срабатывания триггера.
2) Не совсем понял как обработать разные нажатия. (У меня  движение камеры завязано на TouchPhase.Moved)

Comment: Плюс у меня не UI элемент

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно в чём суть проблемы. Активация объекта решается стандартными методами юнити разобранными в документации

```
if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) // если есть тач
 {
   hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position), Vector2.zero);// то делаем рейкаст от координаты тача

   if(hit.collider!= null && объект удовлетворяет условиям )// если во чтонибудь попали 
   {
       DoStuff();// делаем что нам нужно 
   }
}
```

Comment: Да просто думал что event trigger (pointerclick) будет работать на 2d sprite, а он походу работает только с ui. Вот в этот и был косяк... Спасиб (Как раз встал вопрос разделения нажатия и передвижения камеры))